# Mass and Density in De Rerum Natura

Tags: metaphysics, history-of-philosophy, philosophy-of-physics, lucretious

Lucretious poem, *De Rerum Natura* has the following:

> Again, why see we among objects some
>
> Of heavier weight, but of no bulkier size?
>
> Indeed, if in a ball of wool there be
>
> As much of body as in lump of lead,
>
> The two should weigh alike, since body tends
>
> To load things downward, while the void abides,
>
> By contrary nature, the imponderable.
>
> Therefore, an object just as large but lighter
>
> Declares infallibly its more of void

This appears to be a qualitative understanding of *mass* in Antique Physics; given that if 'a ball of wool there be as much body as in a lump of lead' then 'the two should weigh alike'; whilst still tied up with the notion of Aristotelian mass which moves *downward*.

Further, 'an object just as large but lighter declares infallibly its more of void'; expresses a qualitative understanding of density, in that a lighter object just has less *mass* and more *void*.

At least this is my interpretation - is there any corrobative contemporary writings  that support this interpretation?

Finally, is *void* the correct translation of the term Lucretious's poem, given that the Parmenidian Void doesn't express *space* as such; but is of pure absence; and that Lucretian Physics developed out of the Parmenidian critique. What are the two respective terms in the original Greek?

Comment: See Max Jammer, [Concepts of Mass in Classical and Modern Physics](https://books.google.it/books?id=lYvz0_8aGsMC&pg=PA27) (1961), page 27 : it is a clear understanding of the proportionality between "quantity of matter" and weight.